# Using conditional lookup inside Data Validation in MS Excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have an excel file with:

1. `Table1` of three columns: 'Category','Name','Date'.
2. `Table2` of eighteen columns: 'Product','','',,,,,,,'','','Date'. (i.e. the 18th Column is a date)

I need to create a form with fields for Category, Product, ... , and Date. The condition is this Date should be after the date for the selected category as per `Table1` and the selected product as per `Table2`.

For example:

Table1:

```
Category   Name        Date
A          Category A  01-01-2018
B          Category B  01-01-2020
```

Table2: (For the purpose of simplicity, only showing the relevant columns)

```
Product    Name        Date
P1         Product 1   15-02-2018
P2         Product 2   26-07-2018
P3         Product 3   01-04-2019
```

Now, I need to create a data validation as under (in the third column of this new `Table3`):

```
Category    Product    Date (Data Validation here in this column)
A           P1         <Validate that date should be after both 01-01-2018 and 15-02-2018>
B           P3         <Validate that date should be after both 01-01-2020 and 01-04-2019>
```

If these dates were simply available, I could just add the reference in data validation under "date" category with "between" function. Or use formula even.

But how do I include a condition that requires vlookup from two ranges?

EDIT:

Basically, what I want is to do this:

```
=IF(AND(C4>=VLOOKUP(B4,Table1,3,0),C4>=VLOOKUP(A4,Table2,18,0)),"T","F")
```

So, if we use this formula in a cell, it will return T for condition met, and F for not met. How do I put this in data validation, where it only allows user to enter value in C4(above formula) that yields "T".

Comment: I do not want to use explicit mention of Ranges (such as `A1:B45`) as both Table1 and Table2 range will keep on increasing with time. I need the validation to refer to Table1 and Table2 directly. So probably we will also have to use INDIRECT() along with VLOOKUP() and AND() in the data validation formula.

Comment: Could there be same dates for different product?

Comment: Yes @P.b There can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, have to use Indirect with Table references:

```
=AND(C4>=VLOOKUP(B4,INDIRECT("Table2"),3,0),C4>=VLOOKUP(A4,INDIRECT("Table1"),3,0))
```

Comment: Silly of me. I wrote the formula for the cell, but when I was putting it in the data validation formula, I was putting indirect outside the whole formula.